# Change tracking SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, change-tracking

What is the main difference between begin_version and min_valid_version columns for a particular change tracking enabled table in sys.change_tacking_tables?

I am seeing same values for both the columns for each table (1000+ tables) in my database.

I also tried with truncate and insert operation. But, couldn't see any change.

When can we see the different values for both the columns, please give us the example.

Answer (score 0):

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/change-tracking-catalog-views-sys-change-tracking-tables?view=sql-server-2017,

begin_version - Version of the database when change tracking began for the table. This version is usually indicates when change tracking was enabled, but this value is reset if the table is truncated.

When you enable change tracking on a database level, the version of database at that point is considered as 1.  Every transaction that gets committed on this database increases the version sequentially.  So the begin_version corresponding to each table is basically the version of the database at the time of enabling change_tracking on a particular table.

min_valid_version - Minimum valid version of change tracking information that is available for the table.

Based on the retention period that you configured for the change tracking auto cleanup, your min_valid_version gets updated everytime your autocleanup thread wakes up.  The change tracking auto cleanup thread wakes up every 30 minutes in the background and updates the invalid cleanup version for all databases enabled for change tracking.

For eg, if your retention period is 2 days which is the default, any time this thread wakes up, it will determine the maximum version of the database from the transactions that got committed 2 days ago from now.  You could query sys.dm_tran_commit_table to find more information about this.  commit_ts is the version that I just talked about in the above lines.